# How to dynamically arrange the sequence of columns to be displayed based on the priority set for each column by user .In UI-Grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

User has options for selecting columns he/she wants to see(from a list of check boxes user can select) and they can also set priority for each column i.e which column should be displayed first,second and so on .How to make this happen .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this before. But I think what you can do is sort you **columnDefs** array in the the grid options dynamically. And then do `queueRefresh()`